# How to rotate or animate a 3d object in Unity

Tags: macos, unity-game-engine, animation

I want to create windows & an android app to rotate a house using mouse or mobile device touch screen.
I have added 3d object of a house in Unity as per screenshot.

[image: project screenshot]

When i select Window->Animation, animation pane says no animatable object selected.

Should i create a Gameobject, this project is a normal project.

Please help, how do I proceed to animate it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to select the gameobject in the Hierarchy itself not from Project view

Comment: Thanks, But Gameobject has inbuilt Sphere, Cube, etc. How do I add downloaded 3d objects?

Comment: after importing your 3D model to unity , drag and drop it in to your scene, then select it and then do the same steps

a game object is anything at your scene Hierarchy, where components are the part where it control the functionality of the gameobject.

Example: Button, is a gameobject with button componenet